# How to add not null constraint to a table with 'or' operator so either personal OR work number is required in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

How can I add a not null constraint to a table with 'or' operator? I want either the personal OR work phone number to be present for each entry.

I am trying this:
ALTER TABLE user_data MODIFY ( personal_number NOT NULL || work_number NOT NULL);

but get this error:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Use a comma, not a ||

Answer (score 0):

You need a check constraint that checks each column:

```
ALTER TABLE user_data 
ADD CONSTRAINT check_numbers
  CHECK ( personal_number IS NOT NULL AND work_number IS NULL ) OR 
      ( personal_number IS NULL AND work_number IS NOT NULL )
    )
```

Note this disallows having both present though.  Which may or may not be your business rule.  But I think you have enough now to tweak that if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

To check that at least one of personal and work number is present, you can use the `OR` operator in a `CHECK` constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE user_data
  ADD CONSTRAINT personal_or_work_number_required__chk
  CHECK ( personal_number IS NOT NULL OR work_number IS NOT NULL);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iL-ZzEnu)

*Note: The `||` operator is for string concatenation and is not the logical OR operator.*